# Separating whole date and time in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I only can separate date and time to one column.

How can i separate date and time to **all** columns?

```
Dim DateTime As Date
DateTime = Range("D2").Value

'get date
Range("E2").Value = Int(DateTime)
Range("E2").NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY"

'get time
Range("F2").Value = DateTime - Int(DateTime)
Range("F2").NumberFormat = "hh:mm"
```

[[image: Image of my separate date and time column]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple way to do this. Here is an example

Let's say our worksheet looks like this

[image]

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    
    '~~> Change this to relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    With ws
        '~~. Find last row in column D
        lRow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        '~~> Insert formula in column E to get the date part
        .Range("E2:E" & lRow).Formula = "=DATE(YEAR(D2),MONTH(D2),DAY(D2))"
        '~~> Insert formula in column F to get the time part
        .Range("F2:F" & lRow).Formula = "=TIME(HOUR(D2),MINUTE(D2),SECOND(D2))"
        
        '~~> Convert formulas to values
        .Range("E1:F" & lRow).Value = .Range("E1:F" & lRow).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

**Output**

[image]

**Note**: In the above code, feel free to use `.NumberFormat` to format the range in one go. For example `.Range("E1:E" & lRow).NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY"`

Comment: I would put it in two UDFs, one for time and one for date. Then they can drop the code on any cell they want and pass in the date range.

Comment: I leave that choice to OP :)

Answer (score 0):

### Split Date & Time

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

- Adjust (play with) the values in the constants section.

**The Code**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SplitDateTime()
    
    ' Source (Date & Time)
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sFirst As String = "D2"
    ' Date
    Const dName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dFirst As String = "E2"
    Const dFormat As String = "dd\/mm\/yyyy"
    ' Time
    Const tName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const tFirst As String = "F2"
    Const tFormat As String = "hh:mm:ss"
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim wsrCount As Long
    Dim rCount As Long
    
    ' Source Range (Date & Time)
    With wb.Worksheets(sName).Range(sFirst)
        wsrCount = .Worksheet.Rows.Count
        Dim slCell As Range
        Set slCell = .Resize(wsrCount - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If slCell Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Empty column.", vbCritical, "Split Date & Time"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        rCount = slCell.Row - .Row + 1
        Set srg = .Resize(rCount)
    End With
    
    ' Source Array (Date & Time)
    Dim sData As Variant
    If rCount = 1 Then ' one cell (row) only
        ReDim sData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): sData(1, 1) = srg.Value
    Else ' multiple cells (rows)
        sData = srg.Value
    End If
    
    Dim dData() As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To rCount, 1 To 1) ' Date
    Dim tData() As Variant: ReDim tData(1 To rCount, 1 To 1) ' Time
    
    Dim cValue As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    
    ' Split
    For r = 1 To rCount
        cValue = sData(r, 1)
        If VarType(cValue) = vbDate Then
            dData(r, 1) = Int(cValue) ' Date
            tData(r, 1) = cValue - Int(cValue) ' Time
        End If
    Next r
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Date
    With wb.Worksheets(dName).Range(dFirst)
        .Resize(rCount).NumberFormat = dFormat
        .Resize(rCount).Value = dData
        .Resize(wsrCount - .Row - rCount + 1) _
            .Offset(rCount).Clear
        .Worksheet.Columns(.Column).AutoFit
    End With
        
    ' Time
    With wb.Worksheets(tName).Range(tFirst)
        .Resize(rCount).NumberFormat = tFormat
        .Resize(rCount).Value = tData
        .Resize(wsrCount - .Row - rCount + 1) _
            .Offset(rCount).Clear
        .Worksheet.Columns(.Column).AutoFit
    End With
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Date & time split successfully.", vbInformation, "Split Date & Time"

End Sub
```